# App Engine logs showing HTTP 301 for nonexistent URLs

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running a website on Google App Engine. From time to time I get out-of-control bots or perhaps brute force hacking attempts that I see in my logs. Recently I've had a bot (I presume) trying to access `administrator/index.php` several times a second. That file doesn't exist on my site. If I try to access it, I get the standard `404` and this in my logs:

[image: 404 in logs]

But for the bot I am seeing `HTTP 301` in the logs and I'm wondering why. Does Google interpret the requests as a denial of service or other attack and automatically intervene? I haven't seen documentation stating as much, but I'm not sure why else I would be seeing the `301` instead of `404` for the same URL:

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Any chances of your app responding differently depending on the hostname used (that is if it accepts requests via different hostnames)? I.e. when you expand a 301 log entry - does the hostname shown there matches the one you get on your 404 log entry? Also, not sure if I have some kind of extended logging enabled but upon expanding a 301 log entry I'm seeing a json object & going to protoPayload -> line -> [0] -> logMessage shows something like `redirecting "http://example.com/" to "https://www.example.com/"`. If you are seeing something similar - where does your redirect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log entires shown on the screenshots can be clicked & expanded to view additional information. As mentioned in the comment above two things could be checked there for further analysis of what's going on:

- check the hostname of where the request came to & see if it's not the expected behaviour for that hostname.
- if the json object is shown, navigate to `protoPayload` -> `line` -> `[0]` -> `logMessage` where something like `redirecting "http://example.com/" to "https://www.example.com/"` should be shown which could also clear things up a bit.